# Find the confidence interval of square of the mean $\mu^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

Suppose I have a population, I know the variance $\sigma^2$, but I don't know the mean $\mu$. How to find the confidence interval for the square of the mean $\mu^2$ ?

It's well known that the CI of the mean $\mu$ is $P(a < \mu < b) = 1-\alpha$ where $a = \bar x- z_{\alpha/2}\cdot\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b =  \bar x+ z_{\alpha/2}\cdot\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Since $P(a < \mu < b)=P(2a < 2\mu < 2b) = 1-\alpha$, can I just use $P(a^2 < \mu^2 < b^2) = 1-\alpha$ to find the CI of $\mu^2$?

Similarly, if I want to find the CI of $\mu^2+2\mu$, is it correct to do this: $$P(a^2+2a < \mu^2+2\mu < b^2+2b) = 1-\alpha\,\,?$$

And also, what if I'm not sure that the population follows the standard normal distribution? Is there any generalized formula for the CI?

Comment: You may have some terminology issues: $mu^2= \left(\frac1n \sum x_i\right)^2$ is the *square of the mean* of the population.  But some people would call $\mu^2+\sigma^2= \frac1n \sum (x_i^2)$ the *mean square* of the population.  Meanwhile in terms of *confidence intervals*, $P(a < \mu < b)$ might be seen as a meaningless statement as $\mu$ is a fixed parameter of the population even if it is unknown; the way to recover meaning is to see $a$ and $b$ as random variables.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math here.

Comment: The probabilities won't be exactly same because the corresponding events are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By CLT,

$$ \sqrt{n}\frac {\bar{X} - \mu} {\sigma} \to \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $$

Here the key is you need to recognize that this is a (asymtotic) pivotal quantity: the distribution is independent of the unknown parameter $\mu$, and thus we can compute the quantile $z_{\alpha/2}$, and then invert it to construct the CI.

To construct a similar pivotal quantity involving  $\mu^2$, we may consider the sample $X_i^2$, with

$$ E[X^2] = Var[X] + E[X]^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$$

Since $Var[X^2]$ involve the fourth moment, we just use the sample variance $S_{X^2}^2$ to estimate it, as it is the consistent estimator of $Var[X^2]$:

$$ S_{X^2}^2 = \frac {1} {n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i^2 - \bar{X^2}\right)^2$$

where

$$ \bar{X^2} = \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 $$

is the sample mean. Then by Slutsky and CLT,

$$ \sqrt{n} \frac {\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 - \mu^2} {S_{X^2}} \to \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$$

Hence,

$$ \begin{align} \Pr\left\{-z_{\alpha/2} \leq 
\sqrt{n} \frac {\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 - \mu^2} {S_{X^2}} \leq z_{\alpha/2} \right\} \to 1 - \alpha \\
\Rightarrow \Pr\left\{-z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}} \leq 
\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 - \mu^2 \leq z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}} \right\} \to 1 - \alpha \\
\Rightarrow \Pr\left\{\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 -z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu^2 \leq \bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 + z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}} \right\} \to 1 - \alpha \\
\end{align} $$

As a result,
$$ \left[\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 - z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}},
\bar{X^2} - \sigma^2 + z_{\alpha/2} \frac {S_{X^2}} {\sqrt{n}} \right] $$

is a asymptotic $(1 - \alpha)$ confidence interval for $\mu^2$.

Note that it is just one way to construct the CI; there are other possibilities as well.